# How can convert string time from Mistfit API to date?

Tags: android

I receive value `"startTime":"2014-05-19T10:26:54-04:00"` from API.

How can convert this value to date: `"2014-05-19T10:26:54-04:00"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look here for [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

```
private static SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX");
public Date parse(String date) {
    try {
        return format.parse(date);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```